# Update table field using primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I thought this should be very easy but I am stumped.  I am trying to update certain names in a table and I want to use the primary key field to update the name but I am getting 0 rows updated.

```
UPDATE customers SET last_name='Smith' WHERE customer_id = 11;
```

Comment: What type is `customer_id`?

Comment: Are you sure that the last_name of the customer with id "11" is not having the lastname "Smith" by now? As far as I remember it will show also 0 if there was no change done. 
Also I am wondering: are you just doing this query in your SQL studio like Oracle SQL Developer (then you maybe need to commit your change) or is it a stored proc or similiar where your code is?

Comment: DBs are not checking if you are updating value a to a, just applications do such thing time to time as far as I know... 0 rows updated is shown after update execution. Bryan, that's why I got used to execute `select ...` with same `... where ...` before update. If the select selects something (more than 1 record), it is not really possible, that update won't update those with info you provided so far...

Comment: CUSTOMER_ID is a number field type and name is varchar2 I  want to be able to set a different using where = customer_id(primary key)

Comment: @bryan update the question with additional info...

Comment: @Betlista that's not 100% correct. I am pretty sure mySQL is just giving you a number > 0 if there was an item affected due a change of a property( so "a" -> "b" will show 1 but "a" to "a" will give you 0) you've given in your statement. I thought this also applies to pl-sql.Or did I get your comment wrong and you were just telling this? ;-)

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL develper, the primary key is the customer_id which is a number type the name is varchar2

Comment: @bryan so it might be that you've to commit your change, if auto-commit is not enabled. (please google how to do if you don't know what I mean)
Your query itself is fine.

Comment: Check the row first :" select * from customers WHERE customer_id = 11" . Probably you don't have any rows with customer_id =11 .

Comment: Do check the data first with `select last_name from table where id=11 `

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table customers;

create table customers (
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

insert into Customers(CUSTOMER_ID, LAST_NAME) values(11, 'Doe');

select count(*) from Customers WHERE customer_id = 11;

UPDATE customers SET last_name='Smith' WHERE customer_id = 11;

UPDATE customers SET last_name='Smith' WHERE customer_id = 11;
```

writes (when all selected and executed as script - F5):

```
Table CUSTOMERS created.


1 row inserted.


  COUNT(*)
----------
         1


1 row updated.


1 row updated.
```

in console in Oracle 12c.

Comment: Yes that I was doing I am using 11g and its still not working. When I run select * from customers where cutomer_id = 11; It does not show record 11 it just shows an empty table

Comment: So, why you think it is there then, when your DB says it is not?

Comment: I figured it out I am just its too embarrasing lol to tell you what really happened thanks for the help

Comment: We all need a 4 eyes check time to time ;-) I'd recommend you to delete question, otherwise you will get downvotes ;-)